# From Hummingbirds to Ornithopters: Simulating the Aerodynamics of Flapping Wings

Tags: python, performance, numpy, simulation, numba

## [Ptera Software](https://github.com/camurban/pterasoftware)

*A Flapping Wing Aerodynamics Simulator Written in Python*

[image: output]
[image: logo]

### Motivation

About a year ago, I became fascinated by how animals fly. As an aerospace engineering student, it surprised me that natural flight was barely covered in my courses. I soon realized that the reason why flapping wing aerodynamics isn't taught to undergraduate engineers is that it's insanely complicated.

This only made me more interested. I had some experience with UAV design, so I wanted to find a tool that would help me create a flapping wing micro-air vehicle (MAV), such as the [TU Delft's DelFly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEhu-FePBC0&ab_channel=MAVLabTUDelft). Unfortunately, there were no open-source, easy to use, and fast programs for doing so. Therefore, in a moment of temporary insanity, I decided to write my own!

### Initial Goals

My initial goal for [Ptera Software](https://github.com/camUrban/PteraSoftware) was to create a tool that other researchers and I can use to design the aerodynamics of ornithopters. This is goal zero. I also wanted my software to be:

1. Easy to use
2. Easy to read
3. Easy to maintain
4. Validated
5. Attractive to contributors in the open-source community
6. Fast enough to analyze at least 1000 configurations in 24 hours
   Based on these requirements, I decided that the solver would be a Python implementation of the Unsteady Vortex-Lattice Method (UVLM). I also decided to host the repository on GitHub, and distribute it via PyPI.

### Current State

Like many ignorant non-CS engineers before me, I was confident that creating, debugging, testing, and maintaining a massive project would be as easy as writing a 100-line MATLAB script. Months of coding and therapy later, I had released my 'stable' 1.0.0 package.

I've copied the source code of my unsteady solver below. I did this to abide by the rule that we keep things as native to this site as possible. If you can, I recommend going to the vectorization branch on GitHub and navigate to unsteady_ring_vortex_lattice_method.py. If the vectorization branch is no longer active, go to the latest release's master branch.

#### Unsteady Sover

```
class UnsteadyRingVortexLatticeMethodSolver:
    """This is an aerodynamics solver that uses an unsteady ring vortex lattice method."""

    def __init__(self, unsteady_problem):
        """This is the initialization method."""

        # Initialize this solution's attributes.
        self.num_steps = unsteady_problem.num_steps
        self.delta_time = unsteady_problem.delta_time
        self.steady_problems = unsteady_problem.steady_problems
        self.first_results_step = unsteady_problem.first_results_step

        # Initialize attributes to hold aerodynamic data that pertains to this problem.
        self.current_step = None
        self.current_airplane = None
        self.current_operating_point = None
        self.current_freestream_velocity_geometry_axes = None
        self.current_wing_wing_influences = None
        self.vectorized_current_wing_wing_influences = None
        self.current_freestream_wing_influences = None
        self.vectorized_current_freestream_wing_influences = None
        self.current_wake_wing_influences = None
        self.vectorized_current_wake_wing_influences = None
        self.current_vortex_strengths = None
        self.vectorized_current_vortex_strengths = None
        self.streamline_points = None

        # Initialize attributes to hold geometric data that pertains to this problem.
        self.panels = None
        self.panel_normal_directions = None
        self.panel_areas = None
        self.panel_centers = None
        self.panel_collocation_points = None
        self.panel_back_right_vortex_vertices = None
        self.panel_front_right_vortex_vertices = None
        self.panel_front_left_vortex_vertices = None
        self.panel_back_left_vortex_vertices = None
        self.panel_right_vortex_centers = None
        self.panel_right_vortex_vectors = None
        self.panel_front_vortex_centers = None
        self.panel_front_vortex_vectors = None
        self.panel_left_vortex_centers = None
        self.panel_left_vortex_vectors = None
        self.panel_back_vortex_centers = None
        self.panel_back_vortex_vectors = None
        self.seed_points = None

        # Initialize variables to hold aerodynamic data that pertains details about
        # this panel's location on its wing.
        self.panel_is_trailing_edge = None
        self.panel_is_leading_edge = None
        self.panel_is_left_edge = None
        self.panel_is_right_edge = None

        # Initialize variables to hold aerodynamic data that pertains to this
        # problem's last time step.
        self.last_panel_collocation_points = None
        self.last_panel_vortex_strengths = None
        self.last_panel_back_right_vortex_vertices = None
        self.last_panel_front_right_vortex_vertices = None
        self.last_panel_front_left_vortex_vertices = None
        self.last_panel_back_left_vortex_vertices = None
        self.last_panel_right_vortex_centers = None
        self.last_panel_front_vortex_centers = None
        self.last_panel_left_vortex_centers = None
        self.last_panel_back_vortex_centers = None

        # Initialize variables to hold aerodynamic data that pertains to this
        # problem's wake.
        self.wake_ring_vortex_strengths = None
        self.wake_ring_vortex_front_right_vertices = None
        self.wake_ring_vortex_front_left_vertices = None
        self.wake_ring_vortex_back_left_vertices = None
        self.wake_ring_vortex_back_right_vertices = None

    def run(
        self,
        verbose=True,
        prescribed_wake=True,
        calculate_streamlines=True,
    ):
        """This method runs the solver on the unsteady problem."""

        # Initialize all the airplanes' panels' vortices.
        if verbose:
            print("Initializing all airplanes' panel vortices.")
        self.initialize_panel_vortices()

        # Iterate through the time steps.
        for step in range(self.num_steps):

            # Save attributes to hold the current step, airplane, and operating point.
            self.current_step = step
            self.current_airplane = self.steady_problems[self.current_step].airplane
            self.current_operating_point = self.steady_problems[
                self.current_step
            ].operating_point
            self.current_freestream_velocity_geometry_axes = (
                self.current_operating_point.calculate_freestream_velocity_geometry_axes()
            )
            if verbose:
                print(
                    "\nBeginning time step "
                    + str(self.current_step)
                    + " out of "
                    + str(self.num_steps - 1)
                    + "."
                )

            # Initialize attributes to hold aerodynamic data that pertains to this
            # problem.
            self.current_wing_wing_influences = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, self.current_airplane.num_panels)
            )
            self.vectorized_current_wing_wing_influences = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, self.current_airplane.num_panels)
            )
            self.current_freestream_velocity_geometry_axes = (
                self.current_operating_point.calculate_freestream_velocity_geometry_axes()
            )
            self.current_freestream_wing_influences = np.zeros(
                self.current_airplane.num_panels
            )
            self.vectorized_current_freestream_wing_influences = np.zeros(
                self.current_airplane.num_panels
            )
            self.current_wake_wing_influences = np.zeros(
                self.current_airplane.num_panels
            )
            self.vectorized_current_wake_wing_influences = np.zeros(
                self.current_airplane.num_panels
            )
            self.current_vortex_strengths = np.ones(self.current_airplane.num_panels)
            self.vectorized_current_vortex_strengths = np.ones(
                self.current_airplane.num_panels
            )

            # Initialize attributes to hold geometric data that pertains to this
            # problem.
            self.panels = np.empty(self.current_airplane.num_panels, dtype=object)
            self.panel_normal_directions = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.panel_areas = np.zeros(self.current_airplane.num_panels)
            self.panel_centers = np.zeros((self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3))
            self.panel_collocation_points = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.panel_back_right_vortex_vertices = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.panel_front_right_vortex_vertices = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.panel_front_left_vortex_vertices = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.panel_back_left_vortex_vertices = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.panel_right_vortex_centers = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.panel_right_vortex_vectors = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.panel_front_vortex_centers = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.panel_front_vortex_vectors = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.panel_left_vortex_centers = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.panel_left_vortex_vectors = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.panel_back_vortex_centers = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.panel_back_vortex_vectors = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.seed_points = np.empty((0, 3))

            # Initialize variables to hold details about this panel's location on its
            # wing.
            self.panel_is_trailing_edge = np.zeros(
                self.current_airplane.num_panels, dtype=bool
            )
            self.panel_is_leading_edge = np.zeros(
                self.current_airplane.num_panels, dtype=bool
            )
            self.panel_is_left_edge = np.zeros(
                self.current_airplane.num_panels, dtype=bool
            )
            self.panel_is_right_edge = np.zeros(
                self.current_airplane.num_panels, dtype=bool
            )

            # Initialize variables to hold details about the last airplane's panels.
            self.last_panel_collocation_points = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.last_panel_vortex_strengths = np.zeros(
                self.current_airplane.num_panels
            )
            self.last_panel_back_right_vortex_vertices = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.last_panel_front_right_vortex_vertices = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.last_panel_front_left_vortex_vertices = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.last_panel_back_left_vortex_vertices = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.last_panel_right_vortex_centers = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.last_panel_front_vortex_centers = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.last_panel_left_vortex_centers = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )
            self.last_panel_back_vortex_centers = np.zeros(
                (self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3)
            )

            self.wake_ring_vortex_strengths = np.empty(0)
            self.wake_ring_vortex_front_right_vertices = np.empty((0, 3))
            self.wake_ring_vortex_front_left_vertices = np.empty((0, 3))
            self.wake_ring_vortex_back_left_vertices = np.empty((0, 3))
            self.wake_ring_vortex_back_right_vertices = np.empty((0, 3))

            # Collapse this problem's geometry matrices into 1D ndarrays of attributes.
            if verbose:
                print("Collapsing geometry.")
            self.collapse_geometry()

            # Find the matrix of wing-wing influence coefficients associated with
            # this current_airplane's geometry.
            if verbose:
                print("Calculating the wing-wing influences.")
            self.calculate_wing_wing_influences()

            # Find the vector of freestream-wing influence coefficients associated
            # with this problem.
            if verbose:
                print("Calculating the freestream-wing influences.")
            self.calculate_freestream_wing_influences()

            # Find the vector of wake-wing influence coefficients associated with
            # this problem.
            if verbose:
                print("Calculating the wake-wing influences.")
            self.calculate_wake_wing_influences()

            # Solve for each panel's vortex strength.
            if verbose:
                print("Calculating vortex strengths.")
            self.calculate_vortex_strengths()

            # Solve for the near field forces and moments on each panel.
            if self.current_step >= self.first_results_step:
                if verbose:
                    print("Calculating near field forces.")
                self.calculate_near_field_forces_and_moments()

            # Solve for the near field forces and moments on each panel.
            if verbose:
                print("Shedding wake vortices.")
            self.populate_next_airplanes_wake(prescribed_wake=prescribed_wake)

        # Solve for the location of the streamlines if requested.
        if calculate_streamlines:
            if verbose:
                print("\nCalculating streamlines.")
            self.calculate_streamlines()

    def initialize_panel_vortices(self):
        """This method calculates the locations every problem's airplane's bound
        vortex vertices, and then initializes
        its panels' bound vortices.

        Every panel has a ring vortex, which is a quadrangle whose front vortex leg
        is at the panel's quarter chord.
        The left and right vortex legs run along the panel's left and right legs. If
        the panel is not along the
        trailing edge, they extend backwards and meet the back vortex leg at a length
        of one quarter of the rear
        panel's chord back from the rear panel's front leg. Otherwise, they extend
        back backwards and meet the back
        vortex leg at a length of one quarter of the current panel's chord back from
        the current panel's back leg.
        """

        # Iterate through all the steady problem objects.
        for steady_problem in self.steady_problems:

            this_freestream_velocity_geometry_axes = (
                steady_problem.operating_point.calculate_freestream_velocity_geometry_axes()
            )

            # Iterate through this problem's airplane's wings.
            for wing in steady_problem.airplane.wings:

                # Iterate through the wing's chordwise and spanwise positions.
                for chordwise_position in range(wing.num_chordwise_panels):
                    for spanwise_position in range(wing.num_spanwise_panels):

                        panel = wing.panels[chordwise_position, spanwise_position]

                        front_left_vortex_vertex = panel.front_left_vortex_vertex
                        front_right_vortex_vertex = panel.front_right_vortex_vertex

                        # Define the back left and right vortex vertices based on
                        # whether the panel is along the trailing edge or not.
                        if not panel.is_trailing_edge:
                            next_chordwise_panel = wing.panels[
                                chordwise_position + 1, spanwise_position
                            ]
                            back_left_vortex_vertex = (
                                next_chordwise_panel.front_left_vortex_vertex
                            )
                            back_right_vortex_vertex = (
                                next_chordwise_panel.front_right_vortex_vertex
                            )
                        else:
                            # As these vertices are directly behind the trailing
                            # edge, they are spaced back from their
                            # panel's vertex by one quarter the distance traveled
                            # during a time step. This is to more
                            # accurately predict drag.
                            back_left_vortex_vertex = (
                                front_left_vortex_vertex
                                + (panel.back_left_vertex - panel.front_left_vertex)
                                + this_freestream_velocity_geometry_axes
                                * self.delta_time
                                * 0.25
                            )
                            back_right_vortex_vertex = (
                                front_right_vortex_vertex
                                + (panel.back_right_vertex - panel.front_right_vertex)
                                + this_freestream_velocity_geometry_axes
                                * self.delta_time
                                * 0.25
                            )

                        # Initialize the panel's ring vortex.
                        panel.ring_vortex = ps.aerodynamics.RingVortex(
                            front_right_vertex=front_right_vortex_vertex,
                            front_left_vertex=front_left_vortex_vertex,
                            back_left_vertex=back_left_vortex_vertex,
                            back_right_vertex=back_right_vortex_vertex,
                            strength=None,
                        )

    def collapse_geometry(self):
        """This method converts attributes of the problem's geometry into 1D
        ndarrays. This facilitates vectorization, which speeds up the solver."""

        global_panel_position = 0

        # Iterate through the current airplane's wings.
        for wing in self.current_airplane.wings:

            # Convert this wing's 2D ndarray of panels into a 1D ndarray.
            panels = np.ravel(wing.panels)
            wake_ring_vortices = np.ravel(wing.wake_ring_vortices)

            # Iterate through the 1D ndarray of this wing's panels.
            for panel in panels:

                # Update the solver's list of attributes with this panel's attributes.
                self.panels[global_panel_position] = panel
                self.panel_normal_directions[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.normal_direction
                self.panel_areas[global_panel_position] = panel.area
                self.panel_centers[global_panel_position] = panel.center
                self.panel_collocation_points[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.collocation_point
                self.panel_back_right_vortex_vertices[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.ring_vortex.right_leg.origin
                self.panel_front_right_vortex_vertices[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.ring_vortex.right_leg.termination
                self.panel_front_left_vortex_vertices[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.ring_vortex.left_leg.origin
                self.panel_back_left_vortex_vertices[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.ring_vortex.left_leg.termination
                self.panel_right_vortex_centers[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.ring_vortex.right_leg.center
                self.panel_right_vortex_vectors[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.ring_vortex.right_leg.vector
                self.panel_front_vortex_centers[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.ring_vortex.front_leg.center
                self.panel_front_vortex_vectors[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.ring_vortex.front_leg.vector
                self.panel_left_vortex_centers[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.ring_vortex.left_leg.center
                self.panel_left_vortex_vectors[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.ring_vortex.left_leg.vector
                self.panel_back_vortex_centers[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.ring_vortex.back_leg.center
                self.panel_back_vortex_vectors[
                    global_panel_position, :
                ] = panel.ring_vortex.back_leg.vector
                self.panel_is_trailing_edge[
                    global_panel_position
                ] = panel.is_trailing_edge
                self.panel_is_leading_edge[
                    global_panel_position
                ] = panel.is_leading_edge
                self.panel_is_right_edge[global_panel_position] = panel.is_right_edge
                self.panel_is_left_edge[global_panel_position] = panel.is_left_edge

                # Check if this panel is on the trailing edge.
                if panel.is_trailing_edge:
                    # If it is, calculate it's streamline seed point and add it to
                    # the solver's ndarray of seed points.
                    self.seed_points = np.vstack(
                        (
                            self.seed_points,
                            panel.back_left_vertex
                            + 0.5 * (panel.back_right_vertex - panel.back_left_vertex),
                        )
                    )

                # Increment the global panel position.
                global_panel_position += 1

            for wake_ring_vortex in wake_ring_vortices:
                self.wake_ring_vortex_strengths = np.hstack(
                    (self.wake_ring_vortex_strengths, wake_ring_vortex.strength)
                )
                self.wake_ring_vortex_front_right_vertices = np.vstack(
                    (
                        self.wake_ring_vortex_front_right_vertices,
                        wake_ring_vortex.front_right_vertex,
                    )
                )
                self.wake_ring_vortex_front_left_vertices = np.vstack(
                    (
                        self.wake_ring_vortex_front_left_vertices,
                        wake_ring_vortex.front_left_vertex,
                    )
                )
                self.wake_ring_vortex_back_left_vertices = np.vstack(
                    (
                        self.wake_ring_vortex_back_left_vertices,
                        wake_ring_vortex.back_left_vertex,
                    )
                )
                self.wake_ring_vortex_back_right_vertices = np.vstack(
                    (
                        self.wake_ring_vortex_back_right_vertices,
                        wake_ring_vortex.back_right_vertex,
                    )
                )

        # Initialize a variable to hold the global position of the panel as we
        # iterate through them.
        global_panel_position = 0

        if self.current_step > 0:

            last_airplane = self.steady_problems[self.current_step - 1].airplane

            # Iterate through the current airplane's wings.
            for wing in last_airplane.wings:

                # Convert this wing's 2D ndarray of panels into a 1D ndarray.
                panels = np.ravel(wing.panels)

                # Iterate through the 1D ndarray of this wing's panels.
                for panel in panels:
                    # Update the solver's list of attributes with this panel's
                    # attributes.
                    self.last_panel_collocation_points[
                        global_panel_position, :
                    ] = panel.collocation_point

                    self.last_panel_vortex_strengths[
                        global_panel_position
                    ] = panel.ring_vortex.strength

                    self.last_panel_back_right_vortex_vertices[
                        global_panel_position, :
                    ] = panel.ring_vortex.right_leg.origin

                    self.last_panel_front_right_vortex_vertices[
                        global_panel_position, :
                    ] = panel.ring_vortex.right_leg.termination

                    self.last_panel_front_left_vortex_vertices[
                        global_panel_position, :
                    ] = panel.ring_vortex.left_leg.origin

                    self.last_panel_back_left_vortex_vertices[
                        global_panel_position, :
                    ] = panel.ring_vortex.left_leg.termination

                    self.last_panel_right_vortex_centers[
                        global_panel_position, :
                    ] = panel.ring_vortex.right_leg.center

                    self.last_panel_front_vortex_centers[
                        global_panel_position, :
                    ] = panel.ring_vortex.front_leg.center

                    self.last_panel_left_vortex_centers[
                        global_panel_position, :
                    ] = panel.ring_vortex.left_leg.center

                    self.last_panel_back_vortex_centers[
                        global_panel_position, :
                    ] = panel.ring_vortex.back_leg.center

                    # Increment the global panel position.
                    global_panel_position += 1

    def calculate_wing_wing_influences(self):
        """This method finds the matrix of wing-wing influence coefficients
        associated with this airplane's geometry."""

        # Find the matrix of normalized velocities induced at every panel's
        # collocation point by every panel's ring
        # vortex. The answer is normalized because the solver's vortex strength list
        # was initialized to all ones. This
        # will be updated once the correct vortex strength's are calculated.
        total_influences = ps.aerodynamics.calculate_velocity_induced_by_ring_vortices(
            points=self.panel_collocation_points,
            back_right_vortex_vertices=self.panel_back_right_vortex_vertices,
            front_right_vortex_vertices=self.panel_front_right_vortex_vertices,
            front_left_vortex_vertices=self.panel_front_left_vortex_vertices,
            back_left_vortex_vertices=self.panel_back_left_vortex_vertices,
            strengths=self.current_vortex_strengths,
            collapse=False,
        )

        # Take the batch dot product of the normalized velocities with each panel's
        # normal direction. This is now the
        # problem's matrix of wing-wing influence coefficients.
        self.current_wing_wing_influences = np.einsum(
            "...k,...k->...",
            total_influences,
            np.expand_dims(self.panel_normal_directions, axis=1),
        )

    def calculate_freestream_wing_influences(self):
        """This method finds the vector of freestream-wing influence coefficients
        associated with this problem."""

        # Find the normal components of the freestream velocity on every panel by
        # taking a batch dot product.
        freestream_influences = np.einsum(
            "ij,j->i",
            self.panel_normal_directions,
            self.current_freestream_velocity_geometry_axes,
        )

        # Get the current flapping velocities at every collocation point.
        current_flapping_velocities_at_collocation_points = (
            self.calculate_current_flapping_velocities_at_collocation_points()
        )

        # Find the normal components of every panel's flapping velocities at their
        # collocation points by taking a batch
        # dot product.
        flapping_influences = np.einsum(
            "ij,ij->i",
            self.panel_normal_directions,
            current_flapping_velocities_at_collocation_points,
        )

        # Calculate the total current freestream-wing influences by summing the
        # freestream influences and the
        # flapping influences.
        self.current_freestream_wing_influences = (
            freestream_influences + flapping_influences
        )

    def calculate_wake_wing_influences(self):
        """This method finds the vector of the wake-wing influences associated with
        the problem at this time step."""

        # Check if this time step is not the first time step.
        if self.current_step > 0:

            # Get the wake induced velocities. This is a (M x 3) ndarray with the x,
            # y, and z components of the velocity
            # induced by the entire wake at each of the M panels.
            wake_induced_velocities = ps.aerodynamics.calculate_velocity_induced_by_ring_vortices(
                points=self.panel_collocation_points,
                back_right_vortex_vertices=self.wake_ring_vortex_back_right_vertices,
                front_right_vortex_vertices=self.wake_ring_vortex_front_right_vertices,
                front_left_vortex_vertices=self.wake_ring_vortex_front_left_vertices,
                back_left_vortex_vertices=self.wake_ring_vortex_back_left_vertices,
                strengths=self.wake_ring_vortex_strengths,
                collapse=True,
            )

            # Set the current wake-wing influences to the normal component of the
            # wake induced velocities at each panel.
            self.current_wake_wing_influences = np.einsum(
                "ij,ij->i", wake_induced_velocities, self.panel_normal_directions
            )

        else:

            # If this is the first time step, set the current wake-wing influences to
            # zero everywhere, as there is no
            # wake yet.
            self.current_wake_wing_influences = np.zeros(
                self.current_airplane.num_panels
            )

    def calculate_vortex_strengths(self):
        """This method solves for each panel's vortex strength."""

        # Solve for the strength of each panel's vortex.
        self.current_vortex_strengths = np.linalg.solve(
            self.current_wing_wing_influences,
            -self.current_wake_wing_influences
            - self.current_freestream_wing_influences,
        )

        # Iterate through the panels and update their vortex strengths.
        for panel_num in range(self.panels.size):
            # Get the panel at this location.
            panel = self.panels[panel_num]

            # Update this panel's ring vortex strength.
            panel.ring_vortex.update_strength(self.current_vortex_strengths[panel_num])

    def calculate_solution_velocity(self, points):
        """This function takes in a group of points. At every point, it finds the
        induced velocity due to every vortex
        and the freestream velocity.

        :param points: 2D ndarray of floats
            This variable is an ndarray of shape (N x 3), where N is the number of
            points. Each row contains the x, y,
            and z float coordinates of that point's position in meters.
        :return solution_velocities: 2D ndarray of floats
            The output is the summed effects from every vortex, and from the
            freestream on a given point. The result
            will be of shape (N x 3), where each row identifies the velocity at a
            point. The results units are meters
            per second.
        """

        # Find the vector of velocities induced at every point by every panel's ring
        # vortex. The effect of every ring
        # vortex on each point will be summed.
        ring_vortex_velocities = (
            ps.aerodynamics.calculate_velocity_induced_by_ring_vortices(
                points=points,
                back_right_vortex_vertices=self.panel_back_right_vortex_vertices,
                front_right_vortex_vertices=self.panel_front_right_vortex_vertices,
                front_left_vortex_vertices=self.panel_front_left_vortex_vertices,
                back_left_vortex_vertices=self.panel_back_left_vortex_vertices,
                strengths=self.current_vortex_strengths,
                collapse=True,
            )
        )

        # Find the vector of velocities induced at every point by every wake ring
        # vortex. The effect of every wake ring
        # vortex on each point will be summed.
        wake_ring_vortex_velocities = (
            ps.aerodynamics.calculate_velocity_induced_by_ring_vortices(
                points=points,
                back_right_vortex_vertices=self.wake_ring_vortex_back_right_vertices,
                front_right_vortex_vertices=self.wake_ring_vortex_front_right_vertices,
                front_left_vortex_vertices=self.wake_ring_vortex_front_left_vertices,
                back_left_vortex_vertices=self.wake_ring_vortex_back_left_vertices,
                strengths=self.wake_ring_vortex_strengths,
                collapse=True,
            )
        )

        # Find the total influence of the vortices, which is the sum of the influence
        # due to the bound ring vortices and
        # the wake ring vortices.
        total_vortex_velocities = ring_vortex_velocities + wake_ring_vortex_velocities

        # Calculate and return the solution velocities, which is the sum of the
        # velocities induced by the vortices and
        # freestream at every point.
        solution_velocities = (
            total_vortex_velocities + self.current_freestream_velocity_geometry_axes
        )
        return solution_velocities

    def calculate_near_field_forces_and_moments(self):
        """This method finds the the forces and moments calculated from the near field.

        Citation:
            This method uses logic described on pages 9-11 of "Modeling of
            aerodynamic forces in flapping flight with the Unsteady Vortex Lattice
            Method" by Thomas Lambert.

        Note: The forces and moments calculated are in geometry axes. The moment is
        about the airplane's reference point, which should be at the center of
        gravity. The units are Newtons and Newton-meters.

        :return: None
        """

        # Initialize a variable to hold the global panel position as the panel's are
        # iterate through.
        global_panel_position = 0

        # Initialize three lists of variables, which will hold the effective strength
        # of the line vortices comprising
        # each panel's ring vortex.
        effective_right_vortex_line_strengths = np.zeros(
            self.current_airplane.num_panels
        )
        effective_front_vortex_line_strengths = np.zeros(
            self.current_airplane.num_panels
        )
        effective_left_vortex_line_strengths = np.zeros(
            self.current_airplane.num_panels
        )

        # Iterate through the current_airplane's wings.
        for wing in self.current_airplane.wings:

            # Convert this wing's 2D ndarray of panels into a 1D ndarray.
            panels = np.ravel(wing.panels)

            # Iterate through this wing's 1D ndarray panels.
            for panel in panels:

                # Check if this panel is on its wing's right edge.
                if panel.is_right_edge:

                    # Change the effective right vortex line strength from zero to
                    # this panel's ring vortex's strength.
                    effective_right_vortex_line_strengths[
                        global_panel_position
                    ] = self.current_vortex_strengths[global_panel_position]

                else:

                    # Get the panel directly to the right of this panel.
                    panel_to_right = wing.panels[
                        panel.local_chordwise_position,
                        panel.local_spanwise_position + 1,
                    ]

                    # Change the effective right vortex line strength from zero to
                    # the difference between this panel's
                    # ring vortex's strength, and the ring vortex strength of the
                    # panel to the right of it.
                    effective_right_vortex_line_strengths[global_panel_position] = (
                        self.current_vortex_strengths[global_panel_position]
                        - panel_to_right.ring_vortex.strength
                    )

                # Check if this panel is on its wing's leading edge.
                if panel.is_leading_edge:

                    # Change the effective front vortex line strength from zero to
                    # this panel's ring vortex's strength.
                    effective_front_vortex_line_strengths[
                        global_panel_position
                    ] = self.current_vortex_strengths[global_panel_position]
                else:

                    # Get the panel directly in front of this panel.
                    panel_to_front = wing.panels[
                        panel.local_chordwise_position - 1,
                        panel.local_spanwise_position,
                    ]

                    # Change the effective front vortex line strength from zero to
                    # the difference between this panel's
                    # ring vortex's strength, and the ring vortex strength of the
                    # panel in front of it.
                    effective_front_vortex_line_strengths[global_panel_position] = (
                        self.current_vortex_strengths[global_panel_position]
                        - panel_to_front.ring_vortex.strength
                    )

                # Check if this panel is on its wing's left edge.
                if panel.is_left_edge:

                    # Change the effective left vortex line strength from zero to
                    # this panel's ring vortex's strength.
                    effective_left_vortex_line_strengths[
                        global_panel_position
                    ] = self.current_vortex_strengths[global_panel_position]
                else:

                    # Get the panel directly to the left of this panel.
                    panel_to_left = wing.panels[
                        panel.local_chordwise_position,
                        panel.local_spanwise_position - 1,
                    ]

                    # Change the effective left vortex line strength from zero to the
                    # difference between this panel's
                    # ring vortex's strength, and the ring vortex strength of the
                    # panel to the left of it.
                    effective_left_vortex_line_strengths[global_panel_position] = (
                        self.current_vortex_strengths[global_panel_position]
                        - panel_to_left.ring_vortex.strength
                    )

                # Increment the global panel position.
                global_panel_position += 1

        # Calculate the solution velocities at the centers of the panel's front leg,
        # left leg, and right leg.
        velocities_at_ring_vortex_front_leg_centers = (
            self.calculate_solution_velocity(points=self.panel_front_vortex_centers)
            + self.calculate_current_flapping_velocities_at_front_leg_centers()
        )
        velocities_at_ring_vortex_left_leg_centers = (
            self.calculate_solution_velocity(points=self.panel_left_vortex_centers)
            + self.calculate_current_flapping_velocities_at_left_leg_centers()
        )
        velocities_at_ring_vortex_right_leg_centers = (
            self.calculate_solution_velocity(points=self.panel_right_vortex_centers)
            + self.calculate_current_flapping_velocities_at_right_leg_centers()
        )

        # Using the effective line vortex strengths, and the Kutta-Joukowski theorem
        # to find the near field force in
        # geometry axes on the front leg, left leg, and right leg. Also calculate the
        # unsteady component of the
        # force on each panel, which is derived from the unsteady Bernoulli equation.
        near_field_forces_on_ring_vortex_right_legs_geometry_axes = (
            self.current_operating_point.density
            * np.expand_dims(effective_right_vortex_line_strengths, axis=1)
            * nb_explicit_cross(
                velocities_at_ring_vortex_right_leg_centers,
                self.panel_right_vortex_vectors,
            )
        )
        near_field_forces_on_ring_vortex_front_legs_geometry_axes = (
            self.current_operating_point.density
            * np.expand_dims(effective_front_vortex_line_strengths, axis=1)
            * nb_explicit_cross(
                velocities_at_ring_vortex_front_leg_centers,
                self.panel_front_vortex_vectors,
            )
        )
        near_field_forces_on_ring_vortex_left_legs_geometry_axes = (
            self.current_operating_point.density
            * np.expand_dims(effective_left_vortex_line_strengths, axis=1)
            * nb_explicit_cross(
                velocities_at_ring_vortex_left_leg_centers,
                self.panel_left_vortex_vectors,
            )
        )
        unsteady_near_field_forces_geometry_axes = (
            self.current_operating_point.density
            * np.expand_dims(
                (self.current_vortex_strengths - self.last_panel_vortex_strengths),
                axis=1,
            )
            * np.expand_dims(self.panel_areas, axis=1)
            * self.panel_normal_directions
        )

        # Sum the forces on the legs, and the unsteady force, to calculate the total
        # near field force, in geometry
        # axes, on each panel.
        near_field_forces_geometry_axes = (
            near_field_forces_on_ring_vortex_front_legs_geometry_axes
            + near_field_forces_on_ring_vortex_left_legs_geometry_axes
            + near_field_forces_on_ring_vortex_right_legs_geometry_axes
            + unsteady_near_field_forces_geometry_axes
        )

        # Find the near field moment in geometry axes on the front leg, left leg,
        # and right leg. Also find the
        # moment on each panel due to the unsteady force.
        near_field_moments_on_ring_vortex_front_legs_geometry_axes = nb_explicit_cross(
            self.panel_front_vortex_centers - self.current_airplane.xyz_ref,
            near_field_forces_on_ring_vortex_front_legs_geometry_axes,
        )
        near_field_moments_on_ring_vortex_left_legs_geometry_axes = nb_explicit_cross(
            self.panel_left_vortex_centers - self.current_airplane.xyz_ref,
            near_field_forces_on_ring_vortex_left_legs_geometry_axes,
        )
        near_field_moments_on_ring_vortex_right_legs_geometry_axes = nb_explicit_cross(
            self.panel_right_vortex_centers - self.current_airplane.xyz_ref,
            near_field_forces_on_ring_vortex_right_legs_geometry_axes,
        )
        unsteady_near_field_moments_geometry_axes = nb_explicit_cross(
            self.panel_collocation_points - self.current_airplane.xyz_ref,
            unsteady_near_field_forces_geometry_axes,
        )

        # Sum the moments on the legs, and the unsteady moment, to calculate the
        # total near field moment, in
        # geometry axes, on each panel.
        near_field_moments_geometry_axes = (
            near_field_moments_on_ring_vortex_front_legs_geometry_axes
            + near_field_moments_on_ring_vortex_left_legs_geometry_axes
            + near_field_moments_on_ring_vortex_right_legs_geometry_axes
            + unsteady_near_field_moments_geometry_axes
        )

        # Initialize a variable to hold the global panel position.
        global_panel_position = 0

        # Iterate through this solver's panels.
        for panel in self.panels:
            # Update the force and moment on this panel.
            panel.near_field_force_geometry_axes = near_field_forces_geometry_axes[
                global_panel_position, :
            ]
            panel.near_field_moment_geometry_axes = near_field_moments_geometry_axes[
                global_panel_position, :
            ]

            # Update the pressure on this panel.
            panel.update_pressure()

            # Increment the global panel position.
            global_panel_position += 1

            # Sum up the near field forces and moments on every panel to find the
            # total force and moment on the geometry.
        total_near_field_force_geometry_axes = np.sum(
            near_field_forces_geometry_axes, axis=0
        )
        total_near_field_moment_geometry_axes = np.sum(
            near_field_moments_geometry_axes, axis=0
        )

        # Find the total near field force in wind axes from the rotation matrix and
        # the total near field force in
        # geometry axes.
        self.current_airplane.total_near_field_force_wind_axes = (
            np.transpose(
                self.current_operating_point.calculate_rotation_matrix_wind_axes_to_geometry_axes()
            )
            @ total_near_field_force_geometry_axes
        )

        # Find the total near field moment in wind axes from the rotation matrix and
        # the total near field moment in
        # geometry axes.
        self.current_airplane.total_near_field_moment_wind_axes = (
            np.transpose(
                self.current_operating_point.calculate_rotation_matrix_wind_axes_to_geometry_axes()
            )
            @ total_near_field_moment_geometry_axes
        )

        # Calculate the current_airplane's induced drag coefficient
        induced_drag_coefficient = (
            -self.current_airplane.total_near_field_force_wind_axes[0]
            / self.current_operating_point.calculate_dynamic_pressure()
            / self.current_airplane.s_ref
        )

        # Calculate the current_airplane's side force coefficient.
        side_force_coefficient = (
            self.current_airplane.total_near_field_force_wind_axes[1]
            / self.current_operating_point.calculate_dynamic_pressure()
            / self.current_airplane.s_ref
        )

        # Calculate the current_airplane's lift coefficient.
        lift_coefficient = (
            -self.current_airplane.total_near_field_force_wind_axes[2]
            / self.current_operating_point.calculate_dynamic_pressure()
            / self.current_airplane.s_ref
        )

        # Calculate the current_airplane's rolling moment coefficient.
        rolling_moment_coefficient = (
            self.current_airplane.total_near_field_moment_wind_axes[0]
            / self.current_operating_point.calculate_dynamic_pressure()
            / self.current_airplane.s_ref
            / self.current_airplane.b_ref
        )

        # Calculate the current_airplane's pitching moment coefficient.
        pitching_moment_coefficient = (
            self.current_airplane.total_near_field_moment_wind_axes[1]
            / self.current_operating_point.calculate_dynamic_pressure()
            / self.current_airplane.s_ref
            / self.current_airplane.c_ref
        )

        # Calculate the current_airplane's yawing moment coefficient.
        yawing_moment_coefficient = (
            self.current_airplane.total_near_field_moment_wind_axes[2]
            / self.current_operating_point.calculate_dynamic_pressure()
            / self.current_airplane.s_ref
            / self.current_airplane.b_ref
        )

        self.current_airplane.total_near_field_force_coefficients_wind_axes = np.array(
            [induced_drag_coefficient, side_force_coefficient, lift_coefficient]
        )
        self.current_airplane.total_near_field_moment_coefficients_wind_axes = np.array(
            [
                rolling_moment_coefficient,
                pitching_moment_coefficient,
                yawing_moment_coefficient,
            ]
        )

    def calculate_streamlines(self, num_steps=10, delta_time=0.1):
        """Calculates the location of the streamlines coming off the back of the wings."""

        # Initialize a ndarray to hold this problem's matrix of streamline points.
        self.streamline_points = np.expand_dims(self.seed_points, axis=0)

        # Iterate through the streamline steps.
        for step in range(num_steps):
            # Get the last row of streamline points.
            last_row_streamline_points = self.streamline_points[-1, :, :]

            # Add the freestream velocity to the induced velocity to get the total
            # velocity at each of the last row of
            # streamline points.
            total_velocities = self.calculate_solution_velocity(
                points=last_row_streamline_points
            )

            # Interpolate the positions on a new row of streamline points.
            new_row_streamline_points = (
                last_row_streamline_points + total_velocities * delta_time
            )

            # Stack the new row of streamline points to the bottom of the matrix of
            # streamline points.
            self.streamline_points = np.vstack(
                (
                    self.streamline_points,
                    np.expand_dims(new_row_streamline_points, axis=0),
                )
            )

    def populate_next_airplanes_wake(self, prescribed_wake=True):
        """This method updates the next time step's airplane's wake.

        :param prescribed_wake: Bool, optional
            This parameter determines if the solver uses a prescribed wake model. If
            false it will use a free-wake,
            which may be more accurate but will make the solver significantly slower.
            The default is True.

        :return: None
        """

        # Populate the locations of the next airplane's wake's vortex vertices:
        self.populate_next_airplanes_wake_vortex_vertices(
            prescribed_wake=prescribed_wake
        )

        # Populate the locations of the next airplane's wake vortices.
        self.populate_next_airplanes_wake_vortices()

    def populate_next_airplanes_wake_vortex_vertices(self, prescribed_wake=True):
        """This method populates the locations of the next airplane's wake vortex
        vertices.

        :param prescribed_wake: Bool, optional
            This parameter determines if the solver uses a prescribed wake model. If
            false it will use a free-wake,
            which may be more accurate but will make the solver significantly slower.
            The default is True.
        :return: None
        """

        # Check if this is not the last step.
        if self.current_step < self.num_steps - 1:

            # Get the next airplane object and the current airplane's number of wings.
            next_airplane = self.steady_problems[self.current_step + 1].airplane
            num_wings = len(self.current_airplane.wings)

            # Iterate through the wing positions.
            for wing_num in range(num_wings):

                # Get the wing objects at this position from the current and the next
                # airplane.
                this_wing = self.current_airplane.wings[wing_num]
                next_wing = next_airplane.wings[wing_num]

                # Check if this is the first step.
                if self.current_step == 0:

                    # Get the current wing's number of chordwise and spanwise panels.
                    num_spanwise_panels = this_wing.num_spanwise_panels
                    num_chordwise_panels = this_wing.num_chordwise_panels

                    # Set the chordwise position to be at the trailing edge.
                    chordwise_position = num_chordwise_panels - 1

                    # Initialize a matrix to hold the vertices of the new row of wake
                    # ring vortices.
                    first_row_of_wake_ring_vortex_vertices = np.zeros(
                        (1, num_spanwise_panels + 1, 3)
                    )

                    # Iterate through the spanwise panel positions.
                    for spanwise_position in range(num_spanwise_panels):

                        # Get the next wing's panel object at this location.
                        next_panel = next_wing.panels[
                            chordwise_position, spanwise_position
                        ]

                        # The position of the next front left wake ring vortex vertex
                        # is the next panel's ring vortex's
                        # back left vertex.
                        next_front_left_vertex = next_panel.ring_vortex.back_left_vertex

                        # Add this to the new row of wake ring vortex vertices.
                        first_row_of_wake_ring_vortex_vertices[
                            0, spanwise_position
                        ] = next_front_left_vertex

                        # Check if this panel is on the right edge of the wing.
                        if spanwise_position == (num_spanwise_panels - 1):
                            # The position of the next front right wake ring vortex
                            # vertex is the next panel's ring
                            # vortex's back right vertex.
                            next_front_right_vertex = (
                                next_panel.ring_vortex.back_right_vertex
                            )

                            # Add this to the new row of wake ring vortex vertices.
                            first_row_of_wake_ring_vortex_vertices[
                                0, spanwise_position + 1
                            ] = next_front_right_vertex

                    # Set the next wing's matrix of wake ring vortex vertices to a
                    # copy of the row of new wake ring
                    # vortex vertices. This is correct because this is the first time
                    # step.
                    next_wing.wake_ring_vortex_vertices = np.copy(
                        first_row_of_wake_ring_vortex_vertices
                    )

                    # Initialize variables to hold the number of spanwise vertices.
                    num_spanwise_vertices = num_spanwise_panels + 1

                    # Initialize a new matrix to hold the second row of wake ring
                    # vortex vertices.
                    second_row_of_wake_ring_vortex_vertices = np.zeros(
                        (1, num_spanwise_panels + 1, 3)
                    )

                    # Iterate through the spanwise vertex positions.
                    for spanwise_vertex_position in range(num_spanwise_vertices):

                        # Get the corresponding vertex from the first row.
                        wake_ring_vortex_vertex = next_wing.wake_ring_vortex_vertices[
                            0, spanwise_vertex_position
                        ]

                        if prescribed_wake:

                            # If the wake is prescribed, set the velocity at this
                            # vertex to the freestream velocity.
                            velocity_at_first_row_wake_ring_vortex_vertex = (
                                self.current_freestream_velocity_geometry_axes
                            )
                        else:

                            # If the wake is not prescribed, set the velocity at this
                            # vertex to the solution velocity at
                            # this point.
                            velocity_at_first_row_wake_ring_vortex_vertex = (
                                self.calculate_solution_velocity(
                                    np.expand_dims(wake_ring_vortex_vertex, axis=0)
                                )
                            )

                        # Update the second row with the interpolated position of the
                        # first vertex.
                        second_row_of_wake_ring_vortex_vertices[
                            0, spanwise_vertex_position
                        ] = (
                            wake_ring_vortex_vertex
                            + velocity_at_first_row_wake_ring_vortex_vertex
                            * self.delta_time
                        )

                    # Update the wing's wake ring vortex vertex matrix by vertically
                    # stacking the second row below it.
                    next_wing.wake_ring_vortex_vertices = np.vstack(
                        (
                            next_wing.wake_ring_vortex_vertices,
                            second_row_of_wake_ring_vortex_vertices,
                        )
                    )

                # If this isn't the first step, then do this.
                else:

                    # Set the next wing's wake ring vortex vertex matrix to a copy of
                    # this wing's wake ring vortex
                    # vertex matrix.
                    next_wing.wake_ring_vortex_vertices = np.copy(
                        this_wing.wake_ring_vortex_vertices
                    )

                    # Get the number of chordwise and spanwise vertices.
                    num_chordwise_vertices = next_wing.wake_ring_vortex_vertices.shape[
                        0
                    ]
                    num_spanwise_vertices = next_wing.wake_ring_vortex_vertices.shape[1]

                    # Iterate through the chordwise and spanwise vertex positions.
                    for chordwise_vertex_position in range(num_chordwise_vertices):
                        for spanwise_vertex_position in range(num_spanwise_vertices):

                            # Get the wake ring vortex vertex at this position.
                            wake_ring_vortex_vertex = (
                                next_wing.wake_ring_vortex_vertices[
                                    chordwise_vertex_position, spanwise_vertex_position
                                ]
                            )

                            if prescribed_wake:

                                # If the wake is prescribed, set the velocity at this
                                # vertex to the freestream velocity.
                                velocity_at_first_row_wake_vortex_vertex = (
                                    self.current_freestream_velocity_geometry_axes
                                )
                            else:

                                # If the wake is not prescribed, set the velocity at
                                # this vertex to the solution
                                # velocity at this point.
                                velocity_at_first_row_wake_vortex_vertex = np.squeeze(
                                    self.calculate_solution_velocity(
                                        np.expand_dims(wake_ring_vortex_vertex, axis=0)
                                    )
                                )

                            # Update the vertex at this point with its interpolated
                            # position.
                            next_wing.wake_ring_vortex_vertices[
                                chordwise_vertex_position, spanwise_vertex_position
                            ] += (
                                velocity_at_first_row_wake_vortex_vertex
                                * self.delta_time
                            )

                    # Set the chordwise position to the trailing edge.
                    chordwise_position = this_wing.num_chordwise_panels - 1

                    # Initialize a new matrix to hold the new first row of wake ring
                    # vortex vertices.
                    first_row_of_wake_ring_vortex_vertices = np.empty(
                        (1, this_wing.num_spanwise_panels + 1, 3)
                    )

                    # Iterate spanwise through the trailing edge panels.
                    for spanwise_position in range(this_wing.num_spanwise_panels):

                        # Get the panel object at this location on the next
                        # airplane's wing object.
                        next_panel = next_wing.panels[
                            chordwise_position, spanwise_position
                        ]

                        # Add the panel object's back left ring vortex vertex to the
                        # matrix of new wake ring vortex
                        # vertices.
                        first_row_of_wake_ring_vortex_vertices[
                            0, spanwise_position
                        ] = next_panel.ring_vortex.back_left_vertex

                        if spanwise_position == (this_wing.num_spanwise_panels - 1):
                            # If the panel object is at the right edge of the wing,
                            # add its back right ring vortex
                            # vertex to the matrix of new wake ring vortex vertices.
                            first_row_of_wake_ring_vortex_vertices[
                                0, spanwise_position + 1
                            ] = next_panel.ring_vortex.back_right_vertex

                    # Stack the new first row of wake ring vortex vertices above the
                    # wing's matrix of wake ring vortex
                    # vertices.
                    next_wing.wake_ring_vortex_vertices = np.vstack(
                        (
                            first_row_of_wake_ring_vortex_vertices,
                            next_wing.wake_ring_vortex_vertices,
                        )
                    )

    def populate_next_airplanes_wake_vortices(self):
        """This method populates the locations of the next airplane's wake vortices."""

        # Check if the current step is not the last step.
        if self.current_step < self.num_steps - 1:

            # Get the next airplane object.
            next_airplane = self.steady_problems[self.current_step + 1].airplane

            # Iterate through the copy of the current airplane's wing positions.
            # for wing_num in range(len(current_airplane_copy.wings)):
            for wing_num in range(len(self.current_airplane.wings)):

                this_wing = self.current_airplane.wings[wing_num]
                next_wing = next_airplane.wings[wing_num]

                # Get the next wing's matrix of wake ring vortex vertices.
                next_wing_wake_ring_vortex_vertices = (
                    next_wing.wake_ring_vortex_vertices
                )

                # Get the wake ring vortices from the this wing copy object.
                this_wing_wake_ring_vortices_copy = pickle.loads(
                    pickle.dumps(
                        self.current_airplane.wings[wing_num].wake_ring_vortices
                    )
                )

                # Find the number of chordwise and spanwise vertices in the next
                # wing's matrix of wake ring vortex
                # vertices.
                num_chordwise_vertices = next_wing_wake_ring_vortex_vertices.shape[0]
                num_spanwise_vertices = next_wing_wake_ring_vortex_vertices.shape[1]

                # Initialize a new matrix to hold the new row of wake ring vortices.
                new_row_of_wake_ring_vortices = np.empty(
                    (1, num_spanwise_vertices - 1), dtype=object
                )

                # Stack the new matrix on top of the copy of this wing's matrix and
                # assign it to the next wing.
                next_wing.wake_ring_vortices = np.vstack(
                    (new_row_of_wake_ring_vortices, this_wing_wake_ring_vortices_copy)
                )

                # Iterate through the vertex positions.
                for chordwise_vertex_position in range(num_chordwise_vertices):
                    for spanwise_vertex_position in range(num_spanwise_vertices):

                        # Set booleans to determine if this vertex is on the right
                        # and/or trailing edge of the wake.
                        has_right_vertex = (
                            spanwise_vertex_position + 1
                        ) < num_spanwise_vertices
                        has_back_vertex = (
                            chordwise_vertex_position + 1
                        ) < num_chordwise_vertices

                        if has_right_vertex and has_back_vertex:

                            # If this position is not on the right or trailing edge
                            # of the wake, get the four vertices
                            # that will be associated with the corresponding ring
                            # vortex at this position.
                            front_left_vertex = next_wing_wake_ring_vortex_vertices[
                                chordwise_vertex_position, spanwise_vertex_position
                            ]
                            front_right_vertex = next_wing_wake_ring_vortex_vertices[
                                chordwise_vertex_position, spanwise_vertex_position + 1
                            ]
                            back_left_vertex = next_wing_wake_ring_vortex_vertices[
                                chordwise_vertex_position + 1, spanwise_vertex_position
                            ]
                            back_right_vertex = next_wing_wake_ring_vortex_vertices[
                                chordwise_vertex_position + 1,
                                spanwise_vertex_position + 1,
                            ]

                            if chordwise_vertex_position > 0:
                                # If this is isn't the front of the wake, update the
                                # position of the ring vortex at this
                                # location.
                                next_wing.wake_ring_vortices[
                                    chordwise_vertex_position, spanwise_vertex_position
                                ].update_position(
                                    front_left_vertex=front_left_vertex,
                                    front_right_vertex=front_right_vertex,
                                    back_left_vertex=back_left_vertex,
                                    back_right_vertex=back_right_vertex,
                                )

                            if chordwise_vertex_position == 0:
                                # If this is the front of the wake, get the vortex
                                # strength from the wing panel's ring
                                # vortex direction in front of it.
                                this_strength_copy = this_wing.panels[
                                    this_wing.num_chordwise_panels - 1,
                                    spanwise_vertex_position,
                                ].ring_vortex.strength

                                # Then, make a new ring vortex at this location,
                                # with the panel's ring vortex's
                                # strength, and add it to the matrix of ring vortices.
                                next_wing.wake_ring_vortices[
                                    chordwise_vertex_position, spanwise_vertex_position
                                ] = ps.aerodynamics.RingVortex(
                                    front_left_vertex=front_left_vertex,
                                    front_right_vertex=front_right_vertex,
                                    back_left_vertex=back_left_vertex,
                                    back_right_vertex=back_right_vertex,
                                    strength=this_strength_copy,
                                )

    def calculate_current_flapping_velocities_at_collocation_points(self):
        """This method gets the velocity due to flapping at all of the current
        airplane's collocation points."""

        # Check if the current step is the first step.
        if self.current_step < 1:
            # Set the flapping velocities to be zero for all points. Then, return the
            # flapping velocities.
            flapping_velocities = np.zeros((self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3))
            return flapping_velocities

        # Get the current airplane's collocation points, and the last airplane's
        # collocation points.
        these_collocations = self.panel_collocation_points
        last_collocations = self.last_panel_collocation_points

        # Calculate and return the flapping velocities.
        flapping_velocities = (these_collocations - last_collocations) / self.delta_time
        return flapping_velocities

    def calculate_current_flapping_velocities_at_right_leg_centers(self):
        """This method gets the velocity due to flapping at the centers of the
        current airplane's bound ring vortices'
        right legs."""

        # Check if the current step is the first step.
        if self.current_step < 1:
            # Set the flapping velocities to be zero for all points. Then, return the
            # flapping velocities.
            flapping_velocities = np.zeros((self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3))
            return flapping_velocities

        # Get the current airplane's bound vortices' right legs' centers, and the
        # last airplane's bound vortices' right
        # legs' centers.
        these_right_leg_centers = self.panel_right_vortex_centers
        last_right_leg_centers = self.last_panel_right_vortex_centers

        # Calculate and return the flapping velocities.
        flapping_velocities = (
            these_right_leg_centers - last_right_leg_centers
        ) / self.delta_time
        return flapping_velocities

    def calculate_current_flapping_velocities_at_front_leg_centers(self):
        """This method gets the velocity due to flapping at the centers of the
        current airplane's bound ring vortices'
        front legs."""

        # Check if the current step is the first step.
        if self.current_step < 1:
            # Set the flapping velocities to be zero for all points. Then, return the
            # flapping velocities.
            flapping_velocities = np.zeros((self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3))
            return flapping_velocities

        # Get the current airplane's bound vortices' front legs' centers, and the
        # last airplane's bound vortices' front
        # legs' centers.
        these_front_leg_centers = self.panel_front_vortex_centers
        last_front_leg_centers = self.last_panel_front_vortex_centers

        # Calculate and return the flapping velocities.
        flapping_velocities = (
            these_front_leg_centers - last_front_leg_centers
        ) / self.delta_time
        return flapping_velocities

    def calculate_current_flapping_velocities_at_left_leg_centers(self):
        """This method gets the velocity due to flapping at the centers of the
        current airplane's bound ring vortices'
        left legs."""

        # Check if the current step is the first step.
        if self.current_step < 1:
            # Set the flapping velocities to be zero for all points. Then, return the
            # flapping velocities.
            flapping_velocities = np.zeros((self.current_airplane.num_panels, 3))
            return flapping_velocities

        # Get the current airplane's bound vortices' left legs' centers, and the last
        # airplane's bound vortices' left
        # legs' centers.
        these_left_leg_centers = self.panel_left_vortex_centers
        last_left_leg_centers = self.last_panel_left_vortex_centers

        # Calculate and return the flapping velocities.
        flapping_velocities = (
            these_left_leg_centers - last_left_leg_centers
        ) / self.delta_time
        return flapping_velocities
```

#### Goals 0-4

I think that my tool satisfies design goals zero through four. It can analyze the forces and moments on user defined geometry that's flapping with user defined motion. Setting and running up a simulation can be done with a script such as:

```
import pterasoftware as ps

example_airplane = ps.geometry.Airplane(
    wings=[
        ps.geometry.Wing(
            symmetric=True,
            wing_cross_sections=[
                ps.geometry.WingCrossSection(
                    airfoil=ps.geometry.Airfoil(name="naca2412",),
                ),
                ps.geometry.WingCrossSection(
                    y_le=5.0, airfoil=ps.geometry.Airfoil(name="naca2412",),
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ],
)

example_operating_point = ps.operating_point.OperatingPoint()

example_problem = ps.problems.SteadyProblem(
    airplane=example_airplane, operating_point=example_operating_point,
)

example_solver = ps.steady_horseshoe_vortex_lattice_method.SteadyHorseshoeVortexLatticeMethodSolver(
    steady_problem=example_problem
)

example_solver.run()

ps.output.draw(
    solver=example_solver, show_delta_pressures=True, show_streamlines=True,
)
```

The source code is heavily commented, uses the Black python formatter, gets an A code quality grade via CodeFactor, has 94% testing coverage, and implements some basic CI techniques. Additionally, I just finished a validation study that compared the solver's output to experimental data:

[image: validation]

Those curves might not be identical, but they are pretty close for a mid-fidelity unsteady fluids solver! A full Navier-Stokes simulation using software like Ansys would be more accurate, but unsteady high-fidelity solvers are the stuff of HPC clusters running one simulation for hours or even days.

While I feel okay with goals zero through four, I've learned that my intuition about these things is most often wrong. So, please feel free to rip apart my project on any of these topics!

#### Goal 5

This is my first ever open-source project, so maybe my expectations are unrealistic. However, I was hoping for more community engagement and use. I've posted about my repository on Reddit, FaceBook, and LinkedIn, and only two people have opened issues on GitHub. Does that sound reasonable given how niche the idea is? Is there anything I can do to increase engagement?

#### Goal 6

The latest version can run a typical simulation in around 156 seconds. This means that in 24 hours, I could do about 553 runs. The latest, non-packaged version (the vectorization branch on GitHub) leans heavily on NumPy and Numba to increase speed. Until recently, a single function in aerodynamics.py, `calculate_velocity_induced_by_line_vortices` was responsible for around 60% of my run time. Thanks to StackOverflow user Jérôme Richard, who answered my optimization question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66750661/can-i-speed-up-this-aerodynamics-calculation-with-numba-vectorization-or-multi), this is no longer the case.

However, my code is still two times too slow. How can I optimize the system as a whole? For example, to increase ease-of-use, I went with a object-oriented approach and store many large instances of custom objects. My class hierarchy can be found in geometry, aerodynamics, and movement.py (not included due to character limit). However, now my code is heavily memory bound, which isn't helping performance

Should I simply focus on parallelizing my calls to the computationally intensive functions? How close to the theoretical speed limit of this simulation using Python and a workstation laptop?

### Future Work

Other features I have planned are:

- Developing a workflow for using Ptera Software to perform system identification for a flapping wing control system
- Modifying the algorithm to analyze hovering flapping wings (right now, the assumptions of the model aren't valid for situations where the vehicle isn't moving forward at some velocity)
- Creating either a CLI or GUI
- Implementing aeroelastic (flexible wing) effects
- Tightening the speed requirement even further (i.e., could the solver run in under 10 seconds?)

How important do you think each of these features would be to users?

### Closing

You can't talk about ornithopters without mentioning Dune...so I hope this project pleases you, and the house Atreides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with your conclusions with your goals, especially 1-3.

I think it's fantastic.

For goal 5 it's hard to say.  I've the feeling it *is* quite a niche project
in a way.  For example I haven't got a clue of how many people are
generally working in that area, let alone looking around for a new
project like this.  It might make sense to push more into academia
though, perhaps there's some way to get a paper out of this, or a talk
with a more inclined audience?

---

I can't say too much on the actual performance, though I'd really
suggest using a good profiler to figure out where the bottlenecks are.
In any case, maybe someone else will give you some more helpful
suggestions on this topic.

---

Now for the code itself, I've got no complaints.  It's clean, very well
documented, naming is fantastic, you've made it *extremely* easy to get
it all set up (assuming you know anything about Python environments - I
suppose you could even have section that spells out the invocations for
people who do not (e.g. I had to `pip install wheel` manually when
trying to install the dependencies (I'm not 100% sure that's a common
problem, just wanted to let you know) and I also knew how to set up a
virtual environment to not clutter things)).

Long term you might benefit from adding type information via the
`typing` module, if at all possible with `numpy` and the other
libraries.

The declarative approach to defining the wings is excellent, even if I
don't understand the topic at all, the examples and test cases are such
a good show case for everything.

---

A couple of tiny things I've noticed now:

```
            if spanwise_position == 0:
                panel.is_left_edge = True
            else:
                panel.is_left_edge = False
```

That can always be simplified to
`panel.is_left_edge = spanwise_position == 0`.  Same goes for other
instances of this pattern of course.

Also consider providing a bit more information in the exceptions, say,
the value that was wrong, if any, or the expected value that didn't
match.  Helps enormously during debugging!

`animate` needs at least a filename parameter for what's now
`animation.gif`, potentially you might want users to specify a
`file`-like object too, but that's just icing on the top.

In general a lot of the methods are pretty long.  If at all possible I'd
suggest finding some opportunities to compress duplicate code segments
and to move inner parts of loops out into their own helper method to
make things a little bit easier to understand.  That would also give you
another opportunity to give those helper methods a good name.

Maybe move some repeated strings into constants (well, global variables,
but treating them as constants), possibly also make them configurable in
the long term.

There's also a number of single-use definitions of variables, a lot
immediately before a `return`.  I'd inline those since I don't see that
the naming gives the reader any hints, the value should already be
described enough as the return value of the method itself.

There's some methods that get invoked over and over.  If it's avoidable,
that is, if the return value doesn't change, simply precompute it and
put it into a reusable variable instead
(e.g. `calculate_near_field_forces_and_moments` has a lot of that with
the `calculate_dynamic_pressure` calls.

You sometimes have this `if verbose: print(...)` pattern - that can be
simplified by using a "proper" logger and providing a configurable log
level, like `logger.trace(...)` would only show up if the log level was
raised high enough to see all the details.

I'm noticing some conversions going on for convenience
(e.g. `np.ravel`).  For performance it might be necessary to compromise
a bit and solve this differently without expensive allocations and
copying.  This is not substantiated by a profiler so far, but it seems
advisable regardless.

Also memory-related, in `geometry.py`, the `x/y/z_ref` variables are
redundant if the `xyz_ref` vector already exists?  I'm not 100% sure
about whether any difference is intentional or not (c.f. `float(...)`),
but this sounds like an excellent case for using accessors or regular
methods to get the individual components of that vector.

The pattern `if x is None: x = []` is easier to write as `x = x or []`,
as long as there's no difference expected wrt. other non-falsy values
(e.g. `bool("")`).  IMO that's usually not the case and the functional
way to write it is shorter.

In `geometry.py`, line 134 the `enumerate` is unnecessary.  I'd also say
this would look better as a functional definition via `sum` and `map`,
but that's probably not super important.

In `populate_coordinates`, there's a `return` in the very nested `if`
block.  Definitely make that block a separate method, it's very hard to
see where things are due to the deep nesting and the quite hidden
`return` statement.  The `return` in the later `try` block is also odd
and can be removed.  I'd also put the parsing of the file into its own
method in order to be able to test it separately from other things.

Apropos test cases, there's a lot of `del` calls in those, are they
actually helping with memory consumption, or are they more for
documentation?

Oh, I'd lowercase `REQUIREMENTS.txt`, that's the
[usual naming convention](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files)
for it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I am finally getting around to implementing some of your suggestions. Could you explain the `x=x or []` syntax please? I've never seen that before, and couldn't find anything via Google.

Comment: Right, I'm not sure what you'd need to search for, it's basically coming from the observation that `or` short-circuits and returns its arguments depending on whether they are "truthy", so `bool(...)` returns `True` for them. That together with the fact that the empty list `[]` is "falsy", you basically get the equivalent of `if not x: x = []` in a very compact form. And of course you can similarly observe this with `and` as well.